# Which alternatives do I have to create an .app package for Mac?

Tags: macos, automator

I have a bunch of shell scripts and executables which I'd like to wrap into a stand-alone .app package for Mac. I'd also need to show an input dialog to the user, so I can grab a value and use it as input of one of my shell scripts.

I've noticed that *Automator* allows you to create a stand-alone application and to add input dialogs to the workflow, but it's not clear to me how to:

- include my executables within the .app package
- specify a relative path when adding a "run shell script" action, so I can execute my executables when the user double clicks the .app

On the other hand, I've found [appify](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps), which explains how to convert a single bash script into a clickable .app. Nice, but I still need the input dialog bit.

Which alternatives do I have to create a .app file with the above requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You could appify to wrap it in a .app bundle, and have the script itself display the input dialog through AppleScript with the `osascript` command:

```
ans="$(osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to activate' \
    -e 'Tell application "System Events" to display dialog "What?" default answer "Fugeddaboutit" buttons {"Yup", "Nope", "Cancel"} default button 1' \
    -e '(button returned of result) & ":" & (text returned of result)' 2>/dev/null)"

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "You cancelled!"
else
    echo "You entered '${ans#*:}', and pushed the ${ans%%:*} button."
fi
```